# Why is Microsoft Exchange so popular?

Tags: exchange-server

Microsoft Exchange [market share](http://www.serverwatch.com/trends/article.php/3682041/Exchange-2007-aka-The-One-That-Got-the-Biggest-Market-Share.htm) [is](http://www.ferris.com/2008/01/31/email-products-market-shares-versions-deployed-migrations-and-software-cost/) [generally](http://blogs.technet.com/b/john_westworth/archive/2008/08/16/exchange-market-share-report-from-ferris.aspx) [quoted](http://blogs.technet.com/b/ucedsg/archive/2008/09/25/what-is-exchange-server-s-market-share.aspx) to be very high.

What are the technological factors which put Exchange at an advantage over its competitors, that is, other alternatives? Are there any open-source options?

Comment: This is probably more a question for ServerFault.com

Comment: @Andrew: You think? Do I have to manually move it there then?

Comment: Yes, just link your account on ServerFault.com and just repost. I think you will get higher quality answers there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.thehostingnews.com/xs-benefits-exchange-enterprises.html

Answer (score 0):

Because there is such a huge market of people using Outlook as a client.  If that is an enterprise wide fact, then the techies find it easier to go with an integrated solution.

Answer (score 0):

A core advantage of Exchange is that it integrates very easily with Microsoft Active Directory. (Same vendor benefit)

Lotus Notes is the main competitor (in the enterprise).

Comment: Actually, IBM Lotus Domino is the equivalent. Lotus Notes is equivalent to Microsoft Outlook.